# Java3D collision

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, java-3d

I'm trying to detect a collision between my third person avatar and a specific object type. In this case it is a PointSound. I tried using the recommended way, using behaviors as shown in the code below. 
This will only work, if there are no interceptions between the bounds of each object.

Could you explain why such strange behavior happens, and if I really have to do a collision detection on my own and possibly using much more resources?

So here two examples, that hopefully narrow down the problem to an understandable level.

***example 1:***

- add Sphere 1 size 10units at position 0,0,0
- add Sphere 2 same size same position
- move sphere 1 up

Result:

- onCollisionStart is being triggered
- sphere 1 moves up
- onCollision is being triggered repeatedly
- sphere 1 leaves sphere 2
- onCollisionStop is triggered **sometimes**

***example 2:***

- add a sphere 1 size 10 units at position 0,0,0
- add a sphere 2 size 10 units at position 0,0,0
- add a sphere 3 size 100 units at position 0,0,0
- move sphere 1 up

result:

- onCollisionStart is being triggered
- sphere 1 moves up
- onCollision is triggered **only once**
- sphere 1 leaves sphere 2
- nothing happens

Now the collision between sphere 1 and 2 will be triggered on startup, but that's it. No more collisions detected.

**CollisionBehavior:**

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.media.j3d.Behavior;
import javax.media.j3d.Bounds;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.WakeupCriterion;
import javax.media.j3d.WakeupOnCollisionEntry;
import javax.media.j3d.WakeupOnCollisionExit;
import javax.media.j3d.WakeupOnCollisionMovement;
import javax.media.j3d.WakeupOr;

public class CollisionDetector extends Behavior {
    WakeupOr orCriteria;
    Bounds bounds1;
    Bounds bounds2;
    CollusionAction action; 

    public static final int COLLISION_START     = 0;
    public static final int COLLISION_DURING    = 1;
    public static final int COLLISION_STOP      = 2;

    public CollisionDetector(Bounds bounds1 , Bounds bounds2, CollusionAction action) {
        System.out.println("Bounds1: "+bounds1);
        System.out.println("Bounds2: "+bounds2);
        this.bounds1 = bounds1;
        this.bounds2 = bounds2;

        this.action = action;
        setSchedulingBounds(bounds1);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        WakeupCriterion[] wakeup = new WakeupCriterion[3];
        wakeup[0] = new WakeupOnCollisionEntry(bounds2);
        wakeup[1] = new WakeupOnCollisionExit(bounds2);
        wakeup[2] = new WakeupOnCollisionMovement(bounds2);

        orCriteria = new WakeupOr(wakeup);
        wakeupOn(orCriteria);
    }

    @Override
    public void processStimulus(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Enumeration criterion) {
        if (!criterion.hasMoreElements()) return;
        WakeupCriterion nextCriterion = (WakeupCriterion)criterion.nextElement();
        if (nextCriterion instanceof WakeupOnCollisionEntry)
            action.onCollisionStart(new CollisionEvent(bounds1, bounds2));
        else if (nextCriterion instanceof WakeupOnCollisionExit)
            action.onCollisionStop(new CollisionEvent(bounds1, bounds2));
        else {
            action.onCollision(new CollisionEvent(bounds1, bounds2));
        }


        wakeupOn(orCriteria);
    }

}
```

**CollisionAction:**

```
public interface CollisionAction {
    public void onCollision(CollisionEvent e);
    public void onCollisionStart(CollisionEvent e);
    public void onCollisionStop(CollisionEvent e);
}
```